# Removing old copper threaded fitting to iron T fitting

Tags: fitting, copper-tubing, pipe-fitting

I have a house with old piping.  My well water slowly eats away at copper piping,  so after 20 years,  the old copper piping is failing.  Most of it has been replaced.  I am installing a new washing machine and need to replace both supply valves.  Copper to a iron elbow.  In dealing with these,  a copper tube that runs to the garden hose outside at the bottom of the iron cold water supply,  a threaded T junction broke.   I have cut off the copper tube and want to remove the offending copper fittong so I can put in a SS plug.  I have been trying cycling heat to break any  chemical bonds.  3/4 inch fittings throughout.

Any suggestions?   I cannot afford right not to start replacing more piping right now with Pex.

Comment: Perhaps just replace the iron T with a new one, if you can unthread it.

Comment: Heat cycling is good idea. + some gentle hammering. The galvanic erosion made the bond strong, maybe permanent. Give us a picture

Comment: Thank you.   Using a brace to keep the  pipes from moving (there were vertically anchored but not horizontally,  and my full weight (260 lb+),  after the multiple heating sessions,  I was able to loosen them